# jquery validation plugin custom rule check for a word

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to create a custom rule for the Jquery Validation Plugin that checks for one specific word.

In this case, the user must answer a question correctly by entering the word "cat" into the input field. The custom rule would need to define the answer as "cat", I was thinking as a variable, and then check for it.

My failed attempt:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("answercheck", function(value, element) { 
  var password = string('hot');
  return value(password); 
}, "Type the correct answer");
```

and the setup:

```
rules: {
    input_answer{
        required: true,
        answercheck: true
    }

messages: {
    input_answer{
        required: "Answer the question",
        answercheck: "Your answer is incorrect"
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you know when validating text on the client like this that the user can see the code , right? - not only that, they can edit the script as well

Comment: You're better off sending the string to a PHP page with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As others have stated, this is not a secure method since anyone could see/manipulate the JavaScript and easily bypass it.**

However, to simply answer your question, here's how it's done. (It's also a good learning exercise about using `addMethod`)...

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod('answercheck', function (value, element) { 
    return this.optional(element) || /^\bcat\b$/.test(value);
}, "Type the correct answer");
```

And you also wouldn't need to specify a message for `answercheck` below, because it's already defined above within the `method` itself.  (You were also missing some braces `{`, colons `:`, and a comma `,` in this code.)

```js
rules: {
    input_answer: { // <- missing colon after input_answer
        required: true,
        answercheck: true
     }
}, // <- missing brace & comma
messages: {
    input_answer: { // <- missing colon after input_answer
        required: "Answer the question"
        //, answercheck: "Your answer is incorrect"  // not needed, specified in method
    } 
} // <- missing brace and maybe a comma depending on what follows
```

[**Working jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ht8Lu/):

http://jsfiddle.net/ht8Lu/

---

[As per the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage), you'll need to construct your own custom method.

> Add a custom validation method. It must consist of a name (must be a
>   legal javascript identifier), a javascript based function and a
>   default string message.
>
> **Arguments:**
>
> **name;** String   The name of the method, used to identify and referencing it, must be a valid javascript identifier
>
> **method;** Callback   The actual method implementation, returning true if an element is valid. First argument: Current value. Second
>   argument: Validated element. Third argument: Parameters.
>
> **message (Optional);** String, Function   The default message to display for this method. Can be a function created by
>   jQuery.validator.format(value). When undefined, an already existing
>   message is used (handy for localization), otherwise the field-specific
>   messages have to be defined.